# StreamBuilder updating only on end of the stream in Flutter

Tags: user-interface, dart, flutter, stream

I have this stream which should handle a heavy workload subdivided in frames:

```
Stream<int> _test() async* {
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){

  ///Heavy workload simulation
  for(int x = 0; x < 100000; x++){
    double _r = Random().nextDouble();
  }
  print(i);
  yield i;
  }
}
```

And then I'm showing a simple indicator using a StreamBuilder:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        StreamBuilder<int>(
          stream: _test(),
          initialData: 0,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
            return Text(
              '${snapshot.data}',

            );
          },
        ),
        RaisedButton(onPressed: () {_test();})
      ],
    ),
  ),

);
```

}

But when I execute the code, all the values of `i` (from 0 to 49) get printed with a little bit of delay, so the `_test` stream is not instantaneous. But the UI only gets updated at 49, so when the stream ends.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`StreamBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) will build its components using the `snapshot` accompanied by `ConnectionState.done`, which in your case is the last value (49) when your `_test()` function finishes execution, because assigning them consecutively won't allow earlier operations to finish.

One solution will be adding `Future.delayed()`. Which will allow each iteration to be streamed completely before moving to the next value. So `_test()` should be modified to :

```
 Stream<int> _test() async* {
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){

      ///Heavy workload simulation
      for(int x = 0; x < 100000; x++){
        double _r = Random().nextDouble();
      }
      print(i);
      // Delay duration is arbitrarily chosen 
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds:10), () {
      });

      yield i;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This answer helped me a lot.  It solved my very similar problem, but I can't fathom why it works.  Can any one provide with or refer me to an explanation?